# Trick for the sum-product problem

Tags: additive-combinatorics

Yesterday I read the Quanta article [How a Strange Grid Reveals Hidden Connections Between Simple Numbers](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-sum-product-problem-shows-how-addition-and-multiplication-constrain-each-other-20190206/) about the sum-product problem:

Let $A$ be a set of integers. Erdös and Szemerédi conjectured that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $c_{\epsilon}>0$ such that

$\max\{|A+A|,|A \cdot A| \}\geq c_{\epsilon}|A|^{2-\epsilon}$.

The Quanta article talks about recent progress in proving this conjecture. While I was reading the article, I was inspired to try to use the identity

$xy=((x+y)^2-x^2-y^2)/2$

to try to prove this conjecture, since I see squaring and adding numbers as more primitive operations than multiplying two numbers. Using this identity and the fact that $|(A+A)^2|=|A+A|$, I found that:

$|A \cdot A|+|A+A| = |A \cdot A|+|(A+A)^2|=|\{x^2+y^2-(x+y)^2:x,y \in A\}|+|\{(x+y)^2:x,y \in A\}| \geq |\{x^2+y^2:x,y \in A\}| = |A^2+A^2|$.

So to prove the conjecture, it suffices to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $c_{\epsilon}>0$ such that

$|A^2+A^2|=|\{x^2+y^2: x,y \in A\}|\geq c_{\epsilon}|A|^{2-\epsilon}$.

A lot is known about the [sum of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem). Not every number can be expressed as the sum of two squares, but many can. My question is is there a known number $n \leq 2$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $c_{\epsilon}>0$ such that

$|A^2+A^2|\geq c_{\epsilon}|A|^{n-\epsilon}$?

Has this strategy been tried before?

Comment: Clearly $n=1$ works because LHS is at least |A|. Clearly, no larger $n$ works because $A$ could be $\{\sqrt{1},\sqrt{2},\dotsc,\sqrt{n}\}$.

Comment: @BorisBukh, I am assuming that $A$ is a set of integers. I'm not sure if that is the standard assumption for this problem though.

Comment: On the other hand $n=1$ certainly works. But I am trying to get something closer to two.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the nice Quanta article, but math-wise, your computation (the one starting with $|A\cdot A|+|A+A|$) seems totally wrong to me.

Comment: @Seva, if you tell me how it's wrong, I will withdraw the question.

Comment: Well, I am suspicious about the only inequality that appears in the computation in question; could you explain it?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein So you are interested in behavior of $B+B$ for $B$ being a set of squares. That is, as far as I know, open. This is related to the question of whether squares is a $\Lambda(4)$-set.

Comment: @seva it is the triangle inequality for set cardinality.

Comment: Still - exactly what is the general inequality you use, and exactly how you apply it?

Comment: @seva $|\{f(x,y):x,y \in A\}|+|\{g(x,y):x,y \in A\}| \geq |\{f(x,y)+g(x,y):x,y \in A\}|$. In this problem, $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-(x+y)^2$ and $g(x,y)=(x+y)^2$.

Comment: Looks nice - but why is this correct?

Comment: @seva, do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Well, unless I am mistaken, here is a counterexample. Take $A=\{0,1,2\}$, $f(x,y)=x$, and $g(x,y)=100y$. Then $|\{f(x,y)\}|=|\{g(x,y)\}|=3$, while $|\{f(x,y)+g(x,y)\}|=9$.

Comment: @Seva it looks like you are correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Seva, Can you also find a counterexample to $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-(x+y)^2$ and $g(x,y)=(x+y)^2$.

Comment: @seva I ask because I still believe that the inequality in my question is true, even though I haven't proven it.

Comment: I do not have any counterexample off-hand, but it absolutely does not mean that the inequality is correct, of course. If you manage to prove it, this would be interesting, but I cannot see any reason for it to hold.

Comment: @seva I will think about this more. Thank you again for your help with this.

Comment: Presumably you also want to bound $1 < n$, since trivially $|A^2 + A^2| \ge |A^2| \ge \frac12 |A|$

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I want $n$ as close to 2 as possible.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the set cardinality triangle inequality fails for $A_k = \{0, \ldots, k\}$ first at $k = 16, 18$ and for all $k \ge 20$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a well-known and difficult open problem. See [Lower bounds for $|A+A|$ if $A$ contains only perfect squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150142/lower-bounds-for-aa-if-a-contains-only-perfect-squares/150147#150147). To repeat my answer from that question, the best lower bound to date is:
$$|A^2+A^2| \geq |A| (\log |A| )^{c \log \log |A|}$$
due to Schoen in 2011 using his bounds on Freiman's theorem.

I think one drawback to your strategy is that the problem you end up with is considerably harder than the original problem. Indeed there are non-trivial polynomial-type lower bounds on the sum-product problem via rather elementary arguments. On the other hand, there isn't any non-trivial polynomial-type lower bound known on the sum of squares problem and Schoen's theorem above relies on two deep results: Freiman's theorem and a deep theorem about squares in arithmetic progressions due to Bombieri, Granville, Pintz using arguments related to Faltings's theorem.

One explanation for this is Boris' first comment / "counterexample". To make progress on the sum of squares problem you need to exploit the fact that the numbers involved are integers, where most of the sum-product technology doesn't distinguish between real numbers and integers (which, generally, is a feature).

Comment: Sanders has improved the lower bound (via improving the bounds for Freiman's theorem) to $\lvert A\rvert \exp((\log \lvert A\rvert)^{c})$ for some constant $c>0$, see Theorem 11.7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0107.pdf